# Show dots on the nth line of a text if it breaks with CSS

Tags: css, line-breaks

I want to show dots on the nth (in my case 2nd) line of a text if it breaks. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868554/2419808) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292922/2419808) answers but I didn't manage to get the thing working in my case.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TReRs/271/).

```
.overme {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    background: #333;
    /*The problematic part is below*/
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: see http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: You stated that `white-space:nowrap;` so how text would wrap into second line? And besides- it's not possible in css, you'll have to use javascript, does this interests you? There are solutions without js, but you'll have problem inserting dots after text because css doesn't know how long is your text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines may it will helps you.

Comment: @Yulian Check my answer for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @Yulian FYI I simplified a lot the JS code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use the webkit only `-webkit-line-clamp` property for 2 lines.

```css
.overme {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    background: #333;

    /*The problematic part is below*/
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
    
.overme {
    white-space: normal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="overme">
    how much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2**

Use an `:after` pseudo element, aligned to the bottom right corner.
This only works if your text is static and you known beforehand that will overflow the container.

```css
.overme {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
}
    
.overme:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '...';
}
```

```html
<div class="overme">
    how much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
</div>
```

---

**Solution 3 - Cross-browser**

This JS solution compares the height of the parent container (div) against the content text. If the text height is greater than the parent's height, then a `.overflows` class is added to the parent.

To test this, delete some text so that it fits all in the parent. You will no longer see the dots.

```js
$(".overme").each(function () {
  var $elem = $(this);
  $elem.addClass($elem[0].scrollHeight > $elem.height() ? 'overflows' : null);
});
```

```css
.overme {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
}
    
.overme.overflows:after {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '...';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overme">
    how much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to line-clamp for non-webkit browsers?

Comment: @Yulian Looks like that only webkit browsers support it. The only way I can think of a cross-browser solution for dynamic text is to do it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this post [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/), it helped me with this and introduces line clamping with various different ways of achieving the results you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
{
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

but not sure the browser support in the future because the property is not stable yet

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.title {
  height: 13px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```