# what to do to shrink large pharagraphs in html/css?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have a large paragraph like:
*hello hi hello hi hello hello hi hello hi hi hello hi hello hi hello hi hello hi hello hi hello hi*
In this the paragraph i just want that if its length is more than the size of my box that i made in my webpage box than it should give such output:
*hello hi hello hi hello hello hi...*
Mean i want it to be written in at most one line. And if length of para is more that the width of the box then i want the output this way:
*hello hi hello hi hello hello hi...*
How to do this thing.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text-overflow CSS truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292708/text-overflow-css-truncation)

Answer (score 1):

This code will allow you to have maximum of two lines of text. The length of text you should manipulate by changing parents width.

```
.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```